# Titanium: How to remove background of Search bar?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

How can I remove the background of search bar ? I tried by changing background color but it also changes cancel button's color !!!

[image]

Thanks...

Comment: Customization might not work on search bar.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan: ya I tried lot but couldn't fix it..

Comment: what if you use the `setHintText` method and set the text to `""` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best alternative to this is creating a custom search bar with Ti.UI.textField and Ti.UI.button.  Add them both to a view and customize it as you please. Finally, just add an event listener to the button click, and voila!

Comment: Thanks for reply... I did the same :D

Comment: I also found that if you add search bar in table, then background changes to white !!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Module: https://github.com/viezel/NappUI

It extends the properties for several UI Elements, including SearchBar, here is the list.

- SearchField BackgroundImage
- Custom Cancel button

  - barColor - background gradient of the button. (similar to navbar)
  - color - color of the button title
  - title - change the default Cancel text
  - font - set the font of the button
- Appearance of the keyboard
- Disable the search icon

To install it, I recommend you to use the new [gitTio](http://gitt.io) command line, this will automatically download the module, install it on the modules folder on Application Support folder and add the proper config line on tiapp.xml.

```
gittio install -g dk.napp.ui
```

And here is an example of a SearchBar using the new properties enabled by this Module

```js
var searchBar = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({
    searchFieldBackgroundImage:"searchbg.png",
    showsScopeBar:true,
    scopeButtonTitles:["hello", "yes"],
    customCancel:{
        barColor:"#333",
        color:"#ddd",
        title:"Hit me",
        font:{
            fontSize:16,
            fontWeight:"bold",
            fontFamily:"Georgia"
        }
    },
    appearance:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_APPEARANCE_ALERT,
    barColor:"transparent",
    disableSearchIcon:true //disables the search icon in the left side
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the gradient blue, I removed it on my app with:

```
var searchBox = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({
  barColor: '#eee'
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 'barColor' doesn't work.  Ti seems to change the color by changing the opacity or hue or something. DannyM's workaround is the best.

I must have wasted a zillion hours making sense of Titanium's background colors, background images, bar colors and their active/inactive cousins.

Conclusion: "Free" software is costly if you count the time you waste on silly bugs and lack of useful documentation.